# Swift - How to pass UInavigationController and also pass variables

Tags: swift

What is the best way to pass a UInavigationController and also pass variables to a new viewController. I know how to do one or the other but not both at the same time. Thank you in advance

this is my current code

```
func(){

       let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("messagesViewController") as! UINavigationController
        let posts = self.postList[indexPath.row]

        //this is the var that i want to past
       //vc.previousViewMessageId = posts.postKey

        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a view controller that can present a second VC. And this VC is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. What you don't know how to do, is to pass data from the first VC, to the navigation controller, then to the second VC.

Here is a brute force solution. It's not beautiful, but it works anyway.

Make your own `UINavigationController` subclass:

```
class DataPasserController: UINavigationController {
    var previousViewMessageId: SomeType?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let vc = self.topViewController as? YourSecondViewController {
            vc.previousViewMessageId = self.previousViewMessageId
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can add a navigation controller in the storyboard, set its class to `DataPasserController`, and connect the second VC to it as its root view controller.

Now suppose you have got an instance of `DataPasserController` by calling `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, you can do this:

```
yourDataPasserControllerInstance.previousViewMessageId = posts.postKey
```

And present the instance!

Comment: is it that apple don't allow embedding of UINavigationController inside "self." I usually create my own nav using views but it would be much easier embeding it inside "self."

Comment: @pprevalon I don't quite understand your question. You can embed a VC in a Navigation Controller in the storyboard, can't you?

Comment: that is a great idea, sometime we overlook the simple things.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a value to your Navigation Controller's Root View Controller, you access  `viewControllers[0]` and cast it to the class of your Messages View Controller (the controller that has the `previousViewMessageId` property):

```
func () {
    let messagesNC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("messagesViewController") as! UINavigationController
    let messagesVC = messagesNC.viewControllers.first as! MessagesViewController

    messagesVC.previousViewMessageId = postList[indexPath.row].postKey

    presentViewController(messagesNC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is simply presenting a view controller... You are skipping the navigation controller.

What you need to do is present the new view controller inside the navigation controller. Once you have done that, it will show correctly. You can also pass the variables after you've created the `vc` variable.

This presents the new viewController (`vc`) within the navigation controller...

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

This sets the variable in the new viewController (`vc`) (you are correct)

```
vc.previousViewMessageId = posts.postKey
```

So complete:

```
func(){

    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("messagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
    let posts = self.postList[indexPath.row]

    //this is the var that i want to past
    vc.previousViewMessageId = posts.postKey

    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
}
```

PS. While not part of the question, I feel I should still mention... Use of the word `self` should be left to necessity only. In other words, don't use it when it isn't needed. for example `self.postList[indexPath.row]` :) 
https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#use-of-self